# How to show "if" condition without else in sequence diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I want to know how do you design an if condition that doesn't have an "else" in your sequence diagrams? I don't know if I have to do it with an alternative because I will have just one case or nothing, so I will not have any alternatives.
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found this document http://www.omg.org/news/meetings/workshops/MDA-SOA-WS_Manual/00-T4_Matthews.pdf in page 54 I found Opt. I searched in the Internet and it seems that it's exactly what I was asking for.

Answer (score 8):

There is no need to include multiple operands.

The specs (17.6.2) just require that you have at least one operand per fragment (there are no additional constraints for `alt` kind).

[image]

So you can do just that

[image]

Also as Thomas noted, you can use **opt**, which is equivalent (emphasis mine):

> An **opt**ion is semantically equivalent to an **alt**ernative CombinedFragment
>   where there is one operand with non-empty content and the second operand is empty.

Answer (score 4):

Use an `opt` fragment like this

[image]

The condition is shown in square brackets. I think, an `alt` would also do with just one case.